# MAC-адреса систем из текущей подсети

Tags: shell, solaris, bash

Можно ли как-то вывести MAC-адреса всех сетевых интерфейсов для систем, которые имеют IP-адрес в подсетях исходной системы (то есть той, на которой запущен скрипт)? Используя `ssh` или `rsh`.

Как получить подсети, я нашел в интернете:

```
subnets=(` ifconfig -a | grep broadcast | gawk '{print $2}'`)
```

Думал воспользоваться командой ifconfig, но в сети пишут следующее:

> Результаты работы команды `ifconfig -а`будут разными в зависимости от того,кто ее вызывает: пользователь root илирядовой пользователь. Это касаетсяобеих версий команды. В первом случаепомимо IP-адресов и параметровотображаются также MAC-адреса.

Мне нужно, чтобы скрипт запускался от имени обычного пользователя, а не только от рута.И как всё это соединить в единый скрипт? Мне нужно для `OS Solaris`. Будут ли отличия в работе, например, от выполнения на `Ubuntu`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала попробуйте (сработает и в unix и в windows)

```
arp -a
```

Получите МАС-адреса из ARP-таблицы. Она постоянно обновляется, со временем можете накопить информацию (долго ждать кстати не надо, новые записи в таблице появятся, например, после ping какого-либо узла, которого ранее в списке не было).

Ещё можно вот так

```
netstat -rn
```

(но сработает только в unix-ах, а запускать желательно на роутере).

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм такой:

1. получаем на исходном сервере адрес широковещательного IP:

   ifconfig -a
2. После слова *broadcast* идёт широковещательный IP. Делаем на него:

   ping -s broadcast_ip

   Остановить вывод нужно комбинацией Ctrl-C или указать размер и количество пакетов в конце команды через пробел.
3. Нам ответят множество машин в подсети (у кого не закрыт ICMP). После чего ARP-таблица машины заполнится. Достаточно будет её просмотреть:

   arp -a

Как видим, достаточно логина обычного пользователя на машину в сети. Не нужно доступов на маршрутизатор и root права.

Answer (score 1):

```
arp-scan -l
```

задать интефейс можно вот так

```
arp-scan -l -I eth0
```

Вот так выводит:

```
192.168.xx.x    00:19:2f:xx:xx:xx       Cisco Systems192.168.xx.x    00:50:22:xx:xx:xx       ZONET TECHNOLOGY, INC.192.168.xx.x    00:1f:c6:xx:xx:xx       ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
```

Answer (score 0):

nmap 192.168.1.0/29 | grep -P 'report|MAC'